# WinUSB Installation Error

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, mount

I'm trying to create a bootable windows USB stick, but when I get to the installation process, it gives me this error:

```
> Installation failed ! Exit code: 512 Log: Formating device... Mounting... mount: block device /home/jelani/Downloads/en_windows_embedded_8.1_industry_pro_with_update_x64_dvd_4065122.iso is write-protected, mounting read-only Copying... Installing grub... Installing for i386-pc platform. grub-install: warning: this GPT partition label contains no BIOS Boot Partition; embedding won't be possible. grub-install: warning: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged.. grub-install: error: will not proceed with blocklists. Error occured ! Syncing... /usr/bin/winusb: line 78: 11716 Terminated              while true; do
    sleep 0.05; echo 'pulse'; done Cleaning... /usr/bin/winusb: line 78: 23374 Terminated              while true; do
    sleep 0.05; echo 'pulse'; done Umounting and removing '/media/winusb_iso_1431566006_3530'... Umounting and removing '/media/winusb_target_1431566006_3530'...
```

Anyone know how I might be able to solve this error? Thanks!

Comment: How did you try to create this bootable USB stick?

Answer (score 0):

install unetbootin from ppa.
ok i know the new version dosent support windows ntfs format...

but i did it.trust me.
format usb drive in fat32 format,then open unetbootin and only choose windows iso and your usb drive.butt dont start process.now when unetbootin is open go to disk app(gnome disk utility) and unmount & format your usb to ntfs. mount it again.
now come back to unetbootin.then you see its done.you can create windows usb.
it takes about 15 min for me.